# node script to executable file

Tags: node.js

is there any way to convert a node script into a kind of executable or package for linux?
For example for sharing a script I don't want to give the source code, just an executable

Any help is welcome

Regards

Comment: You can't really prevent people from extracting the source.

Comment: duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8040423/node-js-code-protection/8041449

Comment: No, you can't protect source.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173232/make-exe-from-node-js-app/8176614#8176614

Comment: @Raynos getting source code from a text file and reverse engineering an executable are very different things. You can protect it to some level. thejh is technically correct :)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you'll be able to do along the lines of protecting code is to obfuscate the code, which makes it harder to read.

[Free Javascript Obfuscator](http://javascriptobfuscator.com/)

However anyone with enough patience and time will still be able to reverse engineer the code.