# Can I run a web app from usb with Bitlocker

Tags: angularjs, node.js, web, xampp, usb

As per the title, can I run a web application (AngularJS) from usb with Bitlocker.

I installed xampp portable, git portable and nodejs in usb. But I don't know my application can run normaly. I need distribute my application to many customer and secure my source code. Please let me know what I do is possible or not.

NOTE: my question is not duplicated with question [Secure distribution of NODEJS application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413123/secure-distribution-of-nodejs-applications)

Many Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Secure distribution of NodeJS applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413123/secure-distribution-of-nodejs-applications)

Comment: I dont think it is duplicated, I wanna distribute my source code (included php api, javascript) via usb stick