# node.js how to protect files?

Tags: node.js

I have a question.

What are the methods to protect node.js javascript files (those run by server, not client). I would not like them to be visible to public in any way.

Any ideas? Permissions, auth, encryption?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8040423/node-js-code-protection

Answer (score 4):

Files that are running on the server are not directly accessible by the client. That should be enough protection. The client never has direct access to the server side scripts, only to the result they produce which is sent to their browser (or whatever they are using to query your server). So you should really not be worried about your javascript files that are run by node.js on your server.

Comment: Yes, but if I have a file called something.js in domain.com/something.js, wouldn't accessing that link open the file?

Comment: No, it won't if you have Node.js running on the server that will execute this file.

Comment: Just to be safe I think I won't place it in www. Or should I just use .htaccess to not allow access to read any files from web?