# valid nodejs code in string to javascript object

Tags: javascript, node.js

My Goal: I am trying to encrypt .js files into .jse and decrypt only when it is running (obfuscate nodejs code).

```
var ffi = require('ffi');

//libpcrypt.so is a library to encrypt and decrypt files
var crypt = ffi.Library('./libpcrypt', {
  'decrypt' : [ 'string', ['string', 'string']]
});

require.extensions[".jse"] = function (module) {
   module.exports = (crypt.decrypt(module.filename, 'out'));
};

console.log(require('./routes.jse'));
```

I know, with cosole.log() source code can be printed out.

**Problem:** Decrypted code is a plain string, I am not able to convert it into a valid javascript object for exports. Is there a way to export the code string I decrypted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your solution (not tested):

```
require.extensions['.jse'] = function(module, filename) {
  var content = crypt.decrypt(fs.readFileSync(filename), 'out')
  return module._compile(content, filename);
};
```

Happy debugging encrypted modules ;)

Comment: Thanks. I saw this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9163557/458816 too. But I get `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`. I thought it is encoding issue and converted to utf-8. but no use.

Comment: This code should work, because this code stolen from working library. Check your sources you are trying to _compile.

Comment: I am still struggling with the error. Do you think it can be encoding issues? Any other suggestions?.

Comment: What do you see on `console.log(content);`? Expected source code? What if replace real code with some simple example like `module.exports = 2 + 2;`

Comment: I see real code. And I tried as simple as `var x = 10`. Still same problem.

Comment: This is the correct solution. I had some other issues in .so.

Answer (score 0):

module.exports is an object you can assign to (ie: module.exports.newFunc = someFunction;)

```
JSON.parse(crypt.decrypt(module.filename, 'out'));
```

**EDIT** So you should make your encrypted file a JSON class OR check out this answer to a similar question [Load "Vanilla" Javascript Libraries into Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171213/load-vanilla-javascript-libraries-into-node-js)

Comment: it didn't work. Because the string is plain and not JSON.stringify generated. 
Parse Error:  `SyntaxError: Unexpected token e`

Comment: @mv945 - So you should make your encrypted file a JSON class OR check out this answer to a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171213/load-vanilla-javascript-libraries-into-node-js

Comment: you pointed me right direction. thanks.. But I cannot accept your answer unless you edit it :)